# PDF describing nth term in continued fraction

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, continued-fractions, uniform-distribution

For a real number r chosen uniformly at random in the range (0,1), what's the marginal Probability Density Function that describes the nth term in the continued fraction representation of r?

What about conditioned on the values of the terms from 1..n-1 ?